# Using regular or dashed lines as fillings for maps in R

Tags: r, mapping

I am making a map in R using spplot to show the number of participants in my survey study per region (in Quebec). My supervisor wants me to add a layer on top of my map to fill in different regions not with colors but with regular or dashed lines or crosses etc. I am currently using the (RColorBrewer) package in R for the colors but does anyone know a package that contains fillings in the formats I have mentioned?
Thanks
[Here I drew the lines with paint to give you an idea of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gE2ca.png)

The code I used to get this map in the first place is this:

```
library(sp)
library(sf)
library(rgdal)
library(classInt)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(broom)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(tmap)
library(leaflet)
my.palette <- brewer.pal(n=9, name = "Oranges")
spplot(quebec, "pred", col.regions = my.palette, at = cutoffs2, cut=7, col = "black")
cutoffs2 <- c(0,1,20,100,200,500,700)
```

Does anybody have package suggestions for the dashed or regular line filling?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Could you please make your question reproducible: include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as df <- data.frame(…) where … is your variables and values or use dput(head(df)). Include the code you have tried. These links should be of help: [mre] and [ask]

Comment: Have you explored the HatchedPolygons package? https://github.com/statnmap/HatchedPolygons

Comment: @SusanSwitzer Thank you for your suggestion, I looked at their options and it seems to me that this package adds basically a square sticker with the line fillings on top of the map... I am looking for something that is like a color filling and would take the shape of the regions in the map. (the sticky square is nice but I'm afraid it is not that accurate).

Comment: You may consider using ggplot's geom_map instead of spplot: https://imaddowzimet.github.io/crosshatch/